# Translation of "Only human"? As in he/she is only human, and we need to remember that?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

As the title says.
Thank you, wise men and women.

Comment: *Memento homo, quia pulvis es et in pulverem reverteris*, remember man, that thou art dust, an to dust thou shalt return. In a Christian context, *pulvis est*, "he or she is dust", will mean exactly that. Riffing on Matthew 26.41 you could also make something of *Caro vero infirma*, "but the flesh is weak".